# Ошибка при использовании базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Я только не давно начал работать с базой данных и не понимаю что тут можно исправить что бы в всё корректно работало

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def muted(ctx):
    #try:
        user_mute = None
        try:
            user_mute = ctx.message.mentions[0]
        except:
            await ctx.send("Вы не упомянули пользователя")

        try:
            text = ' '.join(ctx.message.content.split(' ')[2:])
            val = int(text)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Вы не правильно указали время,Время мута в минутах.\n `++muted nick 30`")

        if not user_mute == None:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("dbmute.db3")
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            sql = f"""
            SELECT EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM muted
                WHERE discord_id = {str(user_mute.id)}
                LIMIT 1);
                """

            cursor.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
            ddd = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print(ddd[0][0])
            if str(ddd[0][0]) == "1": # если есть польователь в базе данных
                #Получение данных с бд
                conn2 = sqlite3.connect("dbmute.db3")
                #conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
                cursor2 = conn2.cursor()

                sql2 = "SELECT discord_id,reports FROM muted WHERE discord_id=?"
                id_discord = str(user_mute.id)
                #cursor.execute('SELECT discord_id,time FROM muted')
                cursor2.execute(sql2, [(f"{id_discord}")])

                data = cursor2.fetchall()
                cursor2.close()
                conn2.close()
                print(data)
                print(12-12)
                reports = data[0][1]
                reports += 1
                print(reports)
                #Конец получения данных с бд
                if str(data[0][0]) == str(user_mute.id): # Проверка правда ли этот челик
                    #Начало изменение базы данных а точнее количество репортовs
                    conn3 = sqlite3.connect("dbmute.db3")
                    cursor3 = conn3.cursor()

                    sql3 = f"""
                    UPDATE muted
                    SET reports = {int(reports)} 
                    WHERE discord_id = {str(id_discord)}
                    """

                    cursor3.execute(sql3)
                    conn3.commit()
                    cursor3.close()
                    conn3.close()
                    print("close connections")
                    #конец изменение репортов

                    #Начало изменение времени
                    connectt = sqlite3.connect("dbmute.db3")
                    cursorrr = connectt.cursor()

                    livetime = datetime.datetime.now() #Получаем сейчашню дату
                    timemins = val
                    try:
                        print(timemins - 12)
                    except:
                        await ctx.send("Вы не правильно указали время,Время мута в минутах.\n `++muted nick 30`")
                    oktime = livetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=timemins)
                    print(livetime)
                    print(oktime)
                    sql = f"""
                    UPDATE muted
                    SET time = {str(oktime)}
                    WHERE discord_id = {str(id_discord)}
                    """

                    cursorrr.execute(sql)

                    connectt.commit()
                    cursorrr.close()
                    connectt.close()
                    #Конец изменениея времени

                    #Начало Выдача мута [Роли]
                    print("fdsdf")
                    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
                    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, Bot.guilds)
                    print(text)
                    print("id test")
                    member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == user_mute.id, guild.members)
                    print(member)
                    print(12-12)
                    addrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Тюрьма")
                    #delaterole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Тюрьма")
                    await member.add_roles(addrole)
                    #await member.remove_roles(delaterole)
                    print("dsfdsfljdksflj")
                    #except:
                    #    await Bot.get_channel(613816178749472816).send("Ошибка в выдачи/удаление роли в команде мута")
                    #Конец выдачи мута [Роли]
                else:
                    pass
            elif str(ddd[0][0]) == "0":
                conn = sqlite3.connect("dbmute.db3")
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                livetime = datetime.datetime.now() #Получаем сейчашню дату
                try:
                    text = ' '.join(ctx.message.content.split(' ')[2:])
                    val = int(text)
                except:
                    await ctx.send("Вы не правильно указали время,Время мута в минутах.\n `++muted nick 30`")

                livetime = datetime.datetime.now() #Получаем сейчашню дату
                timemins = val
                try:
                    print(timemins - 12)
                except:
                    await ctx.send("Вы не правильно указали время,Время мута в минутах.\n `++muted nick 30`")
                oktime = livetime + datetime.timedelta(minutes=timemins)
                print(livetime)
                print(oktime)

                cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO muted
                                VALUES ('{user_mute.id}', '{oktime}', '1')"""
                            )

                # Сохраняем изменения
                conn.commit()
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        else:
            pass
    #except:
    #    emtd = discord.Embed(title='Ето сообщение должно говорить об ошибки так вот либо что то реально сломалось либо ты просто не очень внимательный и написал имя и время не так как надо', description='Пример:**++mute** `время` `nick` ', color=0xff0000)
    #   await ctx.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=emtd)
```

Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command muted:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zederbreys/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zederbreys/Рабочий стол/d/Rewrite bot/rewrite.py", line 401, in muted
    cursorrr.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "16": syntax error
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zederbreys/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/zederbreys/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/zederbreys/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: near "16": syntax error
```

Comment: Добавьте полный стек ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Добавьте запрос на создание таблицы muted из sqlite.

Comment: Категорически! не рекомендуется формировать полные строчки SQL из переменных, это и дыра безопасности, и путаница между разными типами, возможно в последнем и ошибка. Пишите, как в примере из доков - `cursor.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM muted WHERE discord_id =? LIMIT 1);", [user_mute.id])`.

Comment: @AlexTitov,Дыра в безопасности ?,Данный код это чисто серверная часть